# Resampling with Forward fill on a datetime Index stops at the last entry in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = df1.resample('1min').ffill()
```

I am forward filling the missing values of a time series with index as DateTimeIndex for a stock ticker between time 9:15 to 15:30. The last entry in my dataframe has the time as 15:29. So, when I tried to forward fill, the missing times are getting forward filled only until 15:29 but I want the data to be filled until 15:30. How can I achieve this?

I can obviously add a new row with 15:30 as index and put the same value as in the last entry. But looking for a cleaner approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend date\_range in Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688048/how-to-extend-date-range-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No. I want the last entry to be filled until a specified time

Answer (score 0):

Try ffilling twice.

```
df1 = df1.resample('1min').ffill().ffill()
```